# What is the best practice for writing sql queries inside c# code

Tags: c#, coding-style

On my current project I'm using SQL CE. Since it doesn't have support for stored procedures I have to write sql queries inside repository.

Option 1:

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.Append("SELECT");
query.Append("    c.CUSTOMER_ID,");
query.Append("    COALESCE (c.FIRST_NAME, '') + ' ' + COALESCE (c.LAST_NAME, '') AS FULL_NAME");
query.Append("    ct.NAME as CUSTOMER_TYPE");
query.Append("FROM ");
query.Append("    CT_CUSTOMER_TYPE AS ct INNER JOIN CUSTOMER AS c ON ct.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID = c.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID");
```

Option 2:

```
string query = "SELECT c.CUSTOMER_ID, COALESCE (c.FIRST_NAME, '') + ' ' + COALESCE (c.LAST_NAME, '') AS FULL_NAME, ct.NAME as CUSTOMER_TYPE FROM CT_CUSTOMER_TYPE AS ct INNER JOIN CUSTOMER AS c ON ct.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID = c.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID";
```

Option 1 seems like a much more readable, especially when I have 10+ tables in join, but option 2 is faster. 
Which option should I accept and what's the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Option 2 may be a few nanoseconds faster, but when you add the time to actually execute in the database (several milliseconds) a few extra nanaoseconds barely registers as noise.

In any case, there is another option that's the best of both worlds: @-strings:

```
string query = @"
    SELECT
        c.CUSTOMER_ID,
        COALESCE (c.FIRST_NAME, ''_ + ' ' + COALESCE (c.LAST_NAME, '') AS FULL_NAME
        ct.NAME as CUSTOMER_TYPE
    FROM
        CT_CUSTOMER_TYPE AS ct INNER JOIN CUSTOMER AS c
            ON ct.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID = c.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID
    ";
```

Answer (score 7):

Option 3 - use [verbatim string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx):

```
string query = @"
SELECT 
    c.CUSTOMER_ID,
    COALESCE (c.FIRST_NAME, '') + ' ' + COALESCE (c.LAST_NAME, '') AS FULL_NAME,
    ct.NAME as CUSTOMER_TYPE
FROM 
    CT_CUSTOMER_TYPE AS ct 
  INNER JOIN CUSTOMER AS c 
    ON ct.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID = c.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID";
```

Answer (score 5):

I puts SQL string into resource files, it allows easy edit multiline queries, and provides strongly typed named access to that queries even with IntelliSence tooltips.

Comment: This also means that the app has to go and retrieve the resource, could be a minor performance hit there too.

Comment: This is what I do for complex SQL commands. It allows you to edit the SQL as freely as you would in Management Studio, and provides proper syntax colouring. The performance penalty for reading the embedded resource is negligible compared to a database hit.

Comment: your right, it is negligible compared to a db hit... it's about as significant as using the StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Why not option 3:

```
"Select bla bla bla"
"bla bla bla"
"...."
```

one long literal, split to many lines.

Answer (score 0):

I always use the second method as it is much faster. You use up too many lines of code with the first method, leading to a larger overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to this approach:

1. use +, this operator will add string at compile, not run time (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings)
2. this syntax shouldn't change at run time, use const.
3. use indent to format script well.

The goal purpose is keeping readability and reduces data transfer, and there's no run-time performance cost :) , perfect.

```
    string const query = 
    "SELECT c.CUSTOMER_ID, " +
        "COALESCE (c.FIRST_NAME, ''_ + ' ' + COALESCE (c.LAST_NAME, '') AS FULL_NAME, " +
        "ct.NAME as CUSTOMER_TYPE " +
    "FROM CT_CUSTOMER_TYPE AS ct INNER JOIN CUSTOMER AS c " +
        "ON ct.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID = c.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID;";
```

Answer (score -3):

Have you thought about using LINQ?
https://matthewmanela.com/blog/sql-ce-3-5-with-linq-to-sql/

```cs
using(Northwind db = new Northwind(MyConnectionString))
{
    (from p in db.Products).ToList();
    (from p in db.Customers).ToList();
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.coalesce.aspx